# How to implement the Kernighan-Lin Algorithm to find the partition that MAXIMIZE the costs using Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, max, partitioning

I am trying to implement the Kernighan-Lin Algorithm to do my graph partitioning for finding the MAXIMIZED cost instead of the minimized. I have implemented the minimized version using the pseudo code below, however, I am not sure how to modify it so that it finds the maximized value instead.
Here is the pseudo code I used to implement my minimized version.

> 1. function Kernighan-Lin(G(V,E)):
> 2. determine a balanced initial partition of the nodes into sets A and B
> 3. A1 := A; B1 := B
> 4. do
> 5. compute D values for all a in A1 and b in B1
> 6. for (n := 1 to |V|/2)
> 7. find a[i] from A1 and b[j] from B1, such that g[n] = D[a[i]] + D[b[j]] - 2*c[a[i]][b[j]] is maximal
> 8. move a[i] to B1 and b[j] to A1
> 9. remove a[i] and b[j] from further consideration in this pass
> 10. update D values for the elements of A1 = A1 \ a[i] and B1 = B1 \ b[j]
> 11. end for
> 12. find k which maximizes g_max, the sum of g[1],...,g[k]
> 13. if (g_max > 0) then
> 14. Exchange a[1],a[2],...,a[k] with b[1],b[2],...,b[k]
> 15. until (g_max <= 0)
> 16. return G(V,E)

Comment: Can't you just set c[i][j] to -c[i][j] and use the same algorithm?

Comment: Or if negative edge weights aren't permitted, you can map the edge weights to edge_weight[i] = MAX_INT - edge_weight[i]